# Spark: Use of distinct

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I have the following tuple:

```
((aaa,1,2),(sss,3,4))
((bbb,2,3),(aaa,1,2))
((bbb,2,3),(sss,3,4))
((bbb,2,3),(aaa,4,5))
((aaa,4,5),(sss,3,4))
```

Is it possible using distinct()?, with the first element by tuple

```
((aaa,1,2),(sss,3,4))
((bbb,2,3),(aaa,1,2))
((bbb,2,3),(sss,3,4))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want as output. Do you want  one element in the output for each combination of the first element of the first inner tuple and the entire second inner tuple?

Comment: could you be more specific about the logic used to filter the tuples and add some (pseudo) code on how you are trying to approach it? The answers provided do not match with the expected output but it's not clear where the problem is.

Comment: For example in the tuples above: the second `((bbb,2,3), (aaa, X, X)) and ((aaa,4,5), (sss, X, X))`. I want to remove those elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce some concept of "first": an RDD is a (distributed) set, not an ordered list.

So given a function like:

```
def first (t1, t2): return ... #(your logic here to choose between e.g. (aaa,1,2) and (sss,3,4) ...
```

You can simply:

```
theRdd.reduceByKey(first)
```

Comment: Either the question is wrong or this answer is wrong.  This solution does not produce the desired output: The tuple `((aaa,4,5),(sss,3,4))` will be part of the output data and the tuple `((bbb,2,3),(sss,3,4))` will not be part of the output.

Comment: I believe this solution will provide the desired output, for an appropriate definition of first(t1, t2). Look at the solution from Suztomo, it's exactly the same thing based on a first() method systematically choosing the left part of the pair. 
Again, which tuple to keep for each key only depends on the logic provided in the first() method: an RDD is *set*, not a list, there is no general concept of a tuple being "before" another one, so it needs to be provided explicitly.

Comment: Any solution based on `reduceByKey` directly on the given RDD will produce the keys `(aaa,1,2)`,`(bbb,2,3)`, `(aaa,4,5)`. If the expected output on the question is correct, the dataset need some  transformation on the keys as well.

Comment: I agree, I assume the presence of `(bbb,2,3)` instead of `(aaa,4,5)` in the example answer is a typo by the author.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. However it's not `dictinct()`, but `reduceByKey(func, [numTasks])`.

(Assuming you use Scala for your spark job)
Once you get an array of these tuples, create RDD with `sc.parallelize` and call `reduceByKey` method of resulting RDD. At reduceByKey, you can specify how you want to prioritize the values in second element of these tuples. For other RDD related operations, you can refer [Spark Programming Guide / RDD Operations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations).

With spark-shell you can interactively try your function.

```
$ spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.3/bin/spark-shell
...
scala> val tuples = Array(
 |     (("aaa",1,2),("sss",3,4)),
 |     (("bbb",2,3),("aaa",1,2)),
 |     (("bbb",2,3),("sss",3,4)),
 |     (("bbb",2,3),("aaa",4,5)),
 |     (("aaa",4,5),("sss",3,4)))
scala> val tuplesRdd = sc.parallelize(tuples)
scala> val reducedRdd = tuplesRdd.reduceByKey((x, y) => x)
scala> reducedRdd.take(5)
res0: Array[((String, Int, Int), (String, Int, Int))] =
      Array(((aaa,1,2),(sss,3,4)),
            ((aaa,4,5),(sss,3,4)), 
            ((bbb,2,3),(aaa,1,2)))
```

I formatted the last output. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really. I don't need to have two ((aaa,1,2), (sss, X, X))